# How to select a random color in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, colors

I have this little bit of code in which it selects some colors, I would like to know what if I wanted to select a random color between these ones under the code, how could I do that ?

```
extension UIColor {
    static var random: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...2), green: .random(in: 0...2), blue: .random(in: 0...2), alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Colors I would like to pick in my extension

[image]

Comment: If you want to use above 5 colors only then add color code in array and load color from hex string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use only the colours that you added in your question then add your required colour hex string in `Array`.

```
let arrColors = ["ff0000", "228B22", "FFFF00", "800080", "ffa500"] // Use your color hex
```

Now you need to pick random object from above array like this.

```
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrColors.count)))
self.vwNavigationBar.backgroundColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: arrColors[randomIndex])
```

**Function to convert Hex string to Color**

```
func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It should work.

```
 extension UIColor {

     static func random() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor.rgb(CGFloat.random(in: 0..<256), green: CGFloat.random(in: 0..<256), blue: CGFloat.random(in: 0..<256))
     }

     static func rgb(_ red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
      return UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1)
     }

     convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
        assert(red >= 0 && red <= 255, "Invalid red component")
        assert(green >= 0 && green <= 255, "Invalid green component")
        assert(blue >= 0 && blue <= 255, "Invalid blue component")

        self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
     }

     convenience init(rgb: Int) {
        self.init(
          red: (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF,
          green: (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF,
          blue: rgb & 0xFF
       )
      }

    static func getColor() -> UIColor {
       let chooseFrom = [0x064545,0x708545,0x45580] //Add your colors here
       return UIColor.init(rgb: chooseFrom[Int.random(in: 0..<chooseFrom.count)])
     }

   }
```

Comment: in the func random, it shows the error : Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'CGFloat'

Comment: Use CGFloat instead of Int for random value. it will work

Comment: With UIColor.rgb() there is the error : Unexpected non-void return value in void function

Comment: Check it i forgot return from random(). Now it should work

Comment: I don't really understand where i am supposed to insert return ?

Comment: I didn't write return for random().  or just copy all code again it will work.

Comment: Thank you it works but how am i supposed to pick my own colors ?

Comment: Check out i made change. And please mark as right answer if it works.

Comment: @JayPatel, If you aded required color in array then why you write extra code here. You can simple convert hex string to color.

Comment: @Kuldeep He mention in colors in Hex. That's why i wrote code for Hex.

Answer (score 1):

To get a random color from a list of `UIColors`, just call **`randomElement()`** on the `collection` of `UIColor` elements, i.e.

```
extension UIColor {
    static func random(from colors: [UIColor]) -> UIColor? {
        return colors.randomElement()
    }
}
```

You can use it like:

```
let randomColor = UIColor.random(from: [.red, .yellow, .green, .blue, .purple])
```

I've used the sample colors here. Use your own specific colors that you want to use.

In case you have colors in the form of **hex** values, you need to add another method in the extension to convert that `hex` value into `UIColor` instance.

Let me know in case of any issues.